# is There an easy way to convert a large integer into a decmial by adding 0. to the start

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer

I want to convert a large number to a decimal from the left hand side for example

0555555555555556 -> 0.0555555555555556

0333 -> 0.0333

I can think of padding the start of the string, but i want to know are there any better methods out there

Comment: Is your starting point a number or a string? Is your desired result a number or a string?

Comment: i wouldnt mind either as they can be easily interchanged

Comment: divide by the relevant power of 10? But be careful with numbers starting with 0 as they will be interpreted as octal if all digits are below 7. `0555555555555556` is `25131694349166` base 10.

Comment: If you are starting from a string and you do not want to simply prepend a `'0.'` before parsing to float, maybe you could do something like `parseInt('0555555555555556', 10) / Math.pow(10, '0555555555555556'.length);`... but I do not see why you should make your life harder than you need.

Comment: To do a math calculation for this conversion as a number, you'd have to find the number of digits and then divide by that power of 10.  Otherwise, you can do it with string manipulation by stripping off an leading zeroes, then add "0.0" at the front.  With this many digits, you will have to worry about floating point overflow.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

You've said you don't care whether the result is a string or a number, and haven't told us what your starting point is.

Given that, the simplest way I can think of to do it is string concatenation::

```
const result = "0." + original;
```

Or if you want the result as a number:

```
const result = +("0." + original);
```

Live Example:

```js
function convert(original) {
    const result = "0." + original;
    return result;
}

function test(original) {
    console.log(`${original} => ${convert(original)}`);
}

test("0555555555555556");
test("0333");
```

---

Side note: Beware that your `0555555555555556` number is *right on the edge* of the limits of the JavaScript `number` type (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point). One more digit puts you into warning territory where things will get squirrelly in the higher range; two more digits puts you right into the range where values can no longer be held precisely.